# How to reach wsimport while developing webservice client code?

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport

I am writing a webservice client for the first time.

My webservice is in place and I can access it using address like - `http://web.address.to.service:8080/games/allGames`

When accessing the service through browser, `http://web.address.to.service:8080/games/allGames?wsdl` it prints out the expected results.

Now, I want to write the client code... After creating a project on my local `c:\workspace\WsClient` , I open up command prompt to use wsimport.

```
wsimport -s src -d bin http://web.address.to.service:8080/games/allGames?wsdl
```

But this gives me an error that wsimport not found.

When checked in the JDK, i can see wsimport tool present.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you added wsimport (or its hosting directory) to your path so you can look it up without having to provide the full path to the executable?

Comment: no, i dont think so... where exactly i need to add that?

Comment: For Linux use one of the following [methods](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-adding-path/), for windows follow this [guide](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: so i have to add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin` to my path variable? isnt that the JAVA_HOME path?

Comment: does this directory contain the wsimport executable? If so, you should be able to find and invoke the wsimport application. Or what exactly have you meant with `But this gives me an error that wsimport not found.`?

Comment: if I go to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin` and execute `wsimport -help` it prints out the help but even after adding the path to the PATH variable, if now i am in `C:\workspace\WsClient` and type `wsimport -help` I get  `'wsimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Have you restarted your command-line after you've updated the path environment? At least I need to restart it as it otherwise keeps the old path

Comment: My god! Can't believe it was so trivial. Thank you!! :)